# does the support for JMS/RMI Replication in Ehcahe version 3.X stopped?

Tags: caching, redis, memcached, ehcache, hazelcast

I want to upgrade the Ehcache Version to 3.x from 2.10.x and I dont find the support for RMI/JMS replication (RMICacheReplicatorFactory and JMSCacheReplicatorFactory) in Version 3. if Ehcache 3.x does not support RMI/JMS cache replication what is the best alternative (hazelcast/memcached/redis)

Answer (score 0):

The support is indeed discontinued mostly because it gave zero ordering and consistency guarantees. The alternative for Ehcache is [Terracotta clustering](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.4/clustered-cache.html). It offers a proper model where ordering is guaranteed and consistency can be tweaked somewhat.

As to whether it will fit your use case, that's entirely up to you to determine.

Note: I work on Ehcache and Terracotta

Comment: Is clustering on the Terracotta server supported in the free version? I need to setup a second cache server in case the first one fails. Is this possible without the Cluster tool?

Comment: From what I remember, the Terracotta OSS version allows you to have a single active server, but it can have a passive server ready to take over should the active fail. For more details go to the documentation and try it out. http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.8/clustered-cache.html